# Starting a View Controller from a "nested" View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIViewController which has another UIViewController added as a subview:

```
#import "ListViewController.h"

@interface SearchViewController ()

@end

@synthesize listController;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    …

    self.listController =[[ListViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view insertSubview:listController.view belowSubview:mainTabBar];
    self.listController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, tabHeight, screenWidth, (screenHeight-tabHeight));

}
@end
```

The **ListViewController** has a TableView in it. On the click of an item in the TableView, I want to add a UIViewController to the Navigation Controller:

```
#import “PlaceViewController.h"

@interface ListViewController ()

@end

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PlaceViewController *vc = [[PlaceViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

@end
```

This works if the ListViewController is added to the Navigation Controller normally. But, in this case, when the ListViewController is basically "nested" within another, the newly added **PlaceViewController** is not opening. Is there a way to make this work? Thanks

Comment: Since your main controller acts like a container, you have to create a parent/child relation between the container and the controller which has its view added. You should look at some tutorials/docs about custom container view controller on the Internet.

Comment: Have you tried doing `[self.superview.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];` instead of `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`?

Comment: @FabKremer getting `Property superview not found on object ListViewController` with self.superview.navigationController

Comment: Sorry, @user1282637, I meant `[self.parentViewController.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a parent/child relation between the container and the controller which has its view added. Some informations can be found in the intro of https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/ and more on the internet. Just look at custom container view controller.

Then you can get the navigationController property of your container from your ListViewController using the parentViewController property of ListViewController.